# URL rewriting by htaccess

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite URLs using `htaccess` like, in the example below.

My HTTP request is:

```
http://example.com/store1/index.php?page=user/test
```

I would like to get the URL in browser as:

```
http://example.com/store1/user/test.**
```

Also, please note, that the 1st parameter followed by the slashes after `example.com` is not a real folder; so  I am already rewriting it, using this `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+[^/](.*)$ /$1 [QSA]
```

and it works.

But I need to achive the˛`htaccess` rewriting, without affecting the above settings.